# Eclipse and .tml files highlighting not working

Tags: html, eclipse, tapestry

I'm using eclipse Juno EE IDE for Web Developers.

When I open .tml files, they don't show the correct highlighting and auto complete isn't working. I thought this looked just like it's opening it in a text editor. I right clicked the .tml file and clicked open with > HTML editor and I still don't get the correct highlighting.

This works perfectly on my PC at home, I am at work and it doesn't work properly. Please can someone give me a quick heads up on what setting is wrong? I've spent ages looking and trying different editors, but i'm sure it should just work in the html editor.

Thanks,

Edit: When I hover over the underlined closing html tag, it says "The word is not spelt correctly". It's like it's a text editor, only I did right click > open with html editor.

[image: Image showing the issue]

Answer (score 3):

(If not using Tapestry Tools, as uklance mentioned)

Remember that in addition to editing Eclipse's File Association configuration in:

Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations

you should add the *.tml extension in the Content Types configuration in:

Window->Preferences->General->Content Types

there you should chose html or xml and click add to add *.tml

Comment: anyway, I also recommend using the Tapestry Tools plug-in it's a neat.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this, i'll give it a try when I am at work tomorrow. Strangely enough I did have the Tapestry Tools plugin installed both at work and home. At home it works fine, but at university is causes some strange flickering in the toolbar every time I open a file or switch tab, and it causes a hang for around 10-15 seconds each time (which although sounds trivial, drives me nuts after a while), so it had to go :(. Whilst it worked it did seem good but removing it fixed the problem. I now have "Loom" which offers a shortcut to switch between .tml and the class file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Tapestry Tools](http://code.google.com/p/tapestrytools/) eclipse plugin?

Or you can just add a [file association](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-13.htm) for *.tml to the XML or HTML editors.

Another alternative is [using the JSP editor and a custom tld](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5JSPEditorEclipse)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have seen the Tapestry Tools eclipse plugin and it was really good whilst it worked for me (please see comment in other answer). I'll try the file associations to see if that is an issue when I am in work tomorrow. I really appreciate your help.